# When I try to sign up for a new SE site, or log in to even Stack Overflow with a different browser, I keep seeing this page with missing content

Tags: support, bug, login, sign-up

When I try to sign up for a Stack Exchange site that I'm not already signed up for, or if I try to log into one from a browser that I'm not already logged in through (hence relevance for meta.so), I see this sort of screen.  Why?

One thing to note is that most websites are coming up normally for me.  Even SE sites that I don't have a login for look and act completely normal, except when I try to register.

[image]

Comment: Looks like CSS is being blocked on your end.

Comment: Why is it just happening on the login/registration page?  Is there a way to log in or register with this screen when using an Open ID?

Comment: Those pages are served over HTTPS. Are you blocking CSS/JS serving over HTTPS?

Comment: @Oded Could it be something with insecure content?

Comment: I seem to be able to see it just fine on this site: https://www.httpsnow.org/.